# The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments where types are Datasets

Tags: c#

What is wrong with my code, I keep getting the:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'MultiFaceRec.CashierDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(MultiFaceRec.CashierDataSet)'
>   has some invalid arguments

```
private void ProductsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.ProductsBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.ProductDataSet);
}
```

Comment: You are passing `ProductDataSet` but expecting `CashierDataSet`, change call or definition of method

Comment: Is `this.ProductDataSet` a `MultiFaceRec.CashierDataSet`?

Comment: All these edits and nobody wants to change the title?

Comment: @JonB What would you like to change it to? "I was to lazy to google so I thought I might ask here"?

Comment: everybody happy: I crafted a title...

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you're calling the `UpdateAll` method with a parameter of the wrong type. It seems to be taking a parameter of type `MultiFaceRec.CashierDataSet`, but `ProductDataSet` is of a different type.